# django objects не вернет ответ

Tags: django

добрый день у меня возникло проблемы с кодом

```
def test_first(request, user_id,vibor_test_id):
    stimul_id = getFirstQuestionNumber(vibor_test_id)
    nevigation = questionNevigation(stimul_id,user_id,vibor_test_id)
    next = nevigation.get('next')
    previous = nevigation.get('previous')
    fullname = nevigation.get('fullname')
    question = stimul_slov.objects.filter(id=stimul_id,test_id=vibor_test_id).first()
    otvet1 = otvet.objects.filter(stimul_id=stimul_id,test_id=vibor_test_id).first()

    return render(request, 'test.html', {'question': question, 'otvet': otvet, 'stimul_id': stimul_id,
                                         'next':next, 'previous': previous,'user_id': user_id,
                                         'fullname': fullname, 'vibor_test_id': vibor_test_id})

def getFirstQuestionNumber(vibor_test_id):
    question =  stimul_slov.objects.filter(test_id=vibor_test).order_by('id').first()
    return question.id
```

models.py

```
class stimul_slov(models.Model):

    stimulus = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    test_id = models.ForeignKey(vibor_test, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s: %s" % (self.id , self.stimulus)
```

def getFirstQuestionNumber не возвращает ответь в смысле не показывает стимул

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У тебя на входе функции принимается `getFirstQuestionNumber(vibor_test_id)`, однако в самой функции ты пытаешься искать по переменной `vibor_test`:

```
question =  stimul_slov.objects.filter(test_id=**vibor_test**).order_by('id').first()
```

Вполне вероятно, что именно это может приводить к ошибке. Подробнее сказать сложно, поскольку никакого трейсбека ты не предоставил